# multiple and single row selection listview with a gridview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have a question regarding wpf and `ListView`s. I have this program code in my Windows.xaml

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Names" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Telefon" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Adress" Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And in my Windows.xaml.cs i have this code

```
public partial class ListViewGridViewSample : Window
{
    public ListViewGridViewSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "molo", Telefon= 0909090, Adress= "Street" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "moloi", Telefon="99999", Adress= "street2" });
    }
}
```

And my question is, when I execute this program code I get a window with a `ListView`. And now I want to make a selection at a single or multiple rows. Maybe I want to select row number two this would be the User *moloi* and after selecting this row I want to pass on to a message box for example. How can I handle that?

Can someone give me an easy example pls

thank you all

Comment: After you *get a window with a `ListView`*, is `ListView` populated with data? Because I don't see that you set the `ItemsSource` anywhere in your code!

Comment: Yes sure, at the end of the code *lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;*

Comment: OK. So what have you tried so far to achieve what you want? Because as it's currently written, *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: after executing my program i only get a listview with my 3 rows. And what i want is to select one of these rows and pass on to an messagebox for example or a open a textbox after selecting a row of the listbox

Answer (score 0):

ListView has a property called `SelectionMode="Extended"`. That will allow you to set the desired selection mode. To make the selection behavior, you can use `SelectionChanged` event that is also available on the `ListView`. these two things can help you achieve everything you stated above.

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Margin="10"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged">
  <ListView.View>
```

And the code behind for the event:

```
private void lvUsers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.AddedItems - these are the items that have currently been selected
}
```